# Wordpress Preview returns 404

Tags: wordpress

Site has been fine but suddenly if I edit a post and try to save or preview the post/page I'm redirected to a 404 page? 
I've tried saving the permalinks but it has not helped. Any idea what might cause this and how I can fix it? There was a file called .htaccess.preinstall which I have deleted.

Comment: try to update your permalink settings

Comment: Is it happening to just new entires or all existing?

Comment: Thanks both. It wasn't the permalink settings and was happening on all posts. Turns out it is caused by a firewall that has been implemented by my host. They are working to rectify it.